# Query to get foreign key indexes

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, indexing

I am looking for a query in sql server that will show me a list of all foreign key indexes in my database. I have a bunch of indexes within my database and some are on the foreign keys of the tables and I am looking to drop all my indexes except for those against the foreign keys and primary keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a twist of the first answer could do it for ya?:

```
SELECT 
    sc.name + '.' + t.name as tableName,
    OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id) AS [FKey-Name],
    OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) ReferencedTable, 
c.name as ColumnName
, i.name AS ReferencedKeyName
FROM    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
JOIN    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
    AND ic.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
JOIN    sys.indexes i ON i.index_id = ic.index_id
    AND i.object_id = ic.object_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id
    AND c.column_id = ic.column_id  
JOIN    sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN    sys.schemas sc ON sc.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE   t.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY tableName, OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id), columnName
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query that will do what you need.

```
SELECT 
sc.name + '.' + t.name as tableName,
i.name as indexName,
c.name as columnName
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
    AND ic.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.index_id = ic.index_id
    AND i.object_id = ic.object_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id
    AND c.column_id = ic.column_id  
JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas sc ON sc.schema_id = t.schema_id
where t.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY tableName, indexName, columnName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fk.name, 
       OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id) AS parent_table,
       c1.name AS parent_column, 
       OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id) AS referenced_table, 
       c2.name AS referenced_column
    FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
        INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
            ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c1
            ON fkc.parent_object_id = c1.object_id
                AND fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c2
            ON fkc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
                AND fkc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id
```

Comment: so that gives me the constraints but not the index names

Comment: so that still just gives me the table and columns but not the index names